# From within a VM how to idenitfy whether it is an AWS machine or an Azure machine?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cloud

From within a VM how to idenitfy whether it is an AWS machine or an Azure machine? Is there something specific in the BIOS that I can use to idenitfy that will give it away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For AWS instances, there is an endpoint that will return instance metadata http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval

For Azure instances, such endpoint has recently been announced.. don't know much data it has yet, but here's some info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/what-just-happened-to-my-vm-in-vm-metadata-service/

Comment: Thanks Igorek. I also came across this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/accessing-and-using-azure-vm-unique-id/ Since I mainly want to know the VM id this is good?

Another concern I have is my computer can also be a regular laptop that may not be on the cloud. In these cases, the enpoint hopefully returns null information so that I know it is not a cloud device?

Comment: regular computer will likely error out on those URLs.. so might want to handle the exceptions

Comment: when I import Azure instances (classic VMs), I do not get this instance ID. So I am not able to form the link between teh imported instance and the VM that is talking back to my server.